# Is there any way to set key-value pairs in Firebase Crash Reporting?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have used Fabric Crash Analytics, which is having one method `Crashlytics.setString("token", token);` which is used to set custom user details. So that we can recognize the crash better.

So my question is that Is there any way that I can do same for Firebase's Crash Reporting. 
I have used `FirebaseCrash.log("Activity created 123 123");`, but as the name suggests, it is just logging that string.
It would be better if we can do like this:

```
FirebaseCrash.setString("token", token);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way to attach metadata to a crash report in Firebase Crash Reporting.  We're looking into this for a future release.

Comment: yes, it would be great if it can have this feature.